# Xcode Mac -> App with dock like behavior

Tags: macos, xcode5, dock

I wish I could have worded the title better.

Let's say your Dock is on the left side of your screen and you HIDE it. When you move your mouse to the left side of the screen, the dock appears. I want my app to do the same thing. If the user puts their mouse on the left side of the screen, app animates in just like the dock. Then they move their mouse out and it hides.

I only ask for solutions that could be used in the Mac App Store.

Thank you.

Comment: any prefered language? (i'm thinkin of Objective-C or C++)

Comment: should be possible. Yoink does something similar and it is on the AppStore. the only problem is you want to use the side of the screen with the dock and i doubt apple would allow that if it covers the dock. (why would you want that?)

Comment: Probably should move this to AskDifferent?

Comment: Objective C please :) --- Yes, I've seen apps in the Mac App Store do this as well but that was before the sandboxing requirement.

Comment: Anyone have any idea?